# depth camera interpretation of data ROS

Tags: camera, ros, depth, depth-camera

I am using ROS with a depth camera, and the data for each pixel is 4 bytes. Example: 0,0,192,127

I am trying to extract the distance to a point but I don't know what the 4 numbers represent.

Comment: Literally impossible for anyone to say without further context. What kind of camera are you using? How are you getting that data? Etc….Could it be RGBD where the 4th byte is depth?

Comment: @BTables I found out the format is 32fc1, still not sure what to do though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might wanna search for cv_bridge to convert the sensor_msgs::Image to "real" data for further processing. Can have a look at the tutorial here.[Link](https://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials)